# can't hide the actionbar logo

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Somehow it does not work to hide the activity icon in my actionbar. I tried:

> ActionBar ab = activity.getActionBar();
>   ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
>   ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

where is the bug?

Comment: beside setDisplayUseLogoEnabled you need to use setIcon on activity you want to change

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the display option to turn off DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
```